# How to Create Multirange Calendar with Mat-Calendar in Angular

Tags: angular

I'm working on a complex application that requires a multi-range calendar, allowing users to select multiple ranges within one calendar.

I've already implemented a multi-dates calendar, but now I need to convert the selected dates into continuous ranges.

Any ideas on how to accomplish this?

HTML

```
<mat-calendar #calendar (selectedChange)="select($event)[dateClass]="isSelected">
</mat-calendar>
```

TS

```
daysSelected: any[] = [];
event: any;

isSelected = (event: any) => {
  const date =
    event.getFullYear() +
    "-" +
    ("00" + (event.getMonth() + 1)).slice(-2) +
    "-" +
    ("00" + event.getDate()).slice(-2);
  return this.daysSelected.find(x => x == date) ? "selected" : null;
};

select(event: any, calendar: any) {
  const date =
    event.getFullYear() +
    "-" +
    ("00" + (event.getMonth() + 1)).slice(-2) +
    "-" +
    ("00" + event.getDate()).slice(-2);
  const index = this.daysSelected.findIndex(x => x == date);
  if (index < 0) this.daysSelected.push(date);
  else this.daysSelected.splice(index, 1);

  calendar.updateTodaysDate();
}
```

CSS

```
.mat-calendar-body-cell.selected
{
  background-color:red!important;
  border-radius: 50%
}
```